# How can I convert this Kotlin code to Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I don't know Kotlin. How can I convert the below code to Java?

Here is the code:

```
private var checkedRadioButton: CompoundButton? = null

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.radio_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener)

    if (holder.itemView.radio_button.isChecked) 
        checkedRadioButton = holder.itemView.radio_button
}

private val checkedChangeListener =
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
        checkedRadioButton?.apply { setChecked(!isChecked) }
        checkedRadioButton = compoundButton.apply { setChecked(isChecked) }
    }
```

Comment: We gained our knowledge by spending time and effort to learn and study stuff like that. You should do that too. Trust me, knowledge is power.

Comment: so that mean you guys wont share it??

Comment: I though its a place where we help and share knowledge @MustafaYousef

Comment: `I though its a place where we help and share knowledge` stack overflow definitely is. however, it's also a place where a minimum amount of effort is required and it definitely isn't a free coding service, so to improve your question, show what you've tried and what isn't working. just straight up asking "convert this for me into X" doesn't show any effort at all. if you don't have enough knowledge to do _any_ of this, then it's a good sign that you need to do more research yourself first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will look something like this:

```java
private CompoundButton checkedRadioButton = null;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.radio_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
    if (holder.itemView.radio_button.isChecked()) {
        checkedRadioButton = holder.itemView.radio_button;
    }
}

private final CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangeListener =
        (compoundButton, isChecked) -> {
            if (checkedRadioButton != null) {
                checkedRadioButton.setChecked(!isChecked);
            }
            compoundButton.setChecked(isChecked);
            checkedRadioButton = compoundButton;
        };
```

`var` in Kotlin is used to create a variable that can be changed in runtime. `val` creates a variable that can not be changed. [Kotlin Variables](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#variables)

`apply` - it takes an object and in scope `this` will refer to this object, it also returns this object [Kotlin apply](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html)

`checkedChangeListener` is an Implementation of an interface that has only one method, function takes two arguments (`compoundButton` and `isChecked`) [Kotlin SAM conversion](https://jorgecastillo.dev/kotlin-sam-conversions)

`?.` is a null safety operator, it only calls a function when an object is not a null [Safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls)

Comment: `if (holder.itemView.radio_button.isChecked)` might need to be isChecked() instead